# Get Numeric Value out of Access with c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I am trying to get a numeric value out of an Access Database. The code I wrote below sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. When I run the code below I get a MessageBox with the correct answer (**always**). However when I run code in the same way, but instead of asking for MessageBox, I ask for the value to be shown in a label on the Application via label1.text = TValue I get the below mentioned error message in this line:

```
string SearchValue = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

I can also run the code with different columns in the database (filled with integers), but I have the same strange behavior. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I get the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in OCR_Interface.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have written the following function:

```
    static public string GetDataFromDatabase(string TableName, string SearchColumns, string TargetRow, int TargetValue)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = P:\Root_Data.accdb");
        con.Open();

        string SQLstr = "SELECT " + SearchRow + " FROM RootData WHERE " + TargetRow + "=" + TargetValue;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SQLstr, con);
        string SearchValue = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        con.Close();
        return SearchValue;

    }
```

I am calling the function in the following way:

```
        int TestValue = 3000;
        TestValue .ToString();
        string TValue = GetDataFromDatabase("RootData", "Ticker", "Quantity", TestValue);
        MessageBox.Show(TValue);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `string SQLstr = "SELECT " + SearchRow + " FROM RootData WHERE " + TargetRow + "=" + TargetValue;` be `string SQLstr = "SELECT " + SearchColumns + " FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + TargetRow + "=" + TargetValue;`

Comment: `command.ExecuteScalar()` will return `null` if there are no results. If that happens, `command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` is going to throw a `NullReferenceException`. But the easiest approach is just to step through it in the debugger. I'd split that one line up and check for null right after executing the query. You can't assume that you'll get a result.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection.  You variable is called "SearchColumns", but your code is using "SearchRow".

Comment: Thanks, I have amended everything to SearchColums, but still the same problem. @ScottHannen  but in this case I 100% know that the value I am looking for is in the database and in the column I am looking in.

Comment: Maybe the value you're looking for is in the database but the problem is in the query. The simplest thing is to step through it and see where the problem is. You can often guess correctly about a null exception by looking at it. But it probably takes a few seconds to debug. Here's a fun  although borderline irrelevant post: https://www.daedtech.com/i-love-debugger.

Comment: In your question you say that the difference between success and failure is what you're doing after the query - showing it in a MessageBox or putting it in a label. But the error is happening before that - when you execute the query. So something else is different between the two different ways you're calling this.